# Find the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{z}$ where
>   $$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{2}\left [\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-2}{2}}  \right ]$$
>
> and where $z_0=2$

Now I know that
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_n(z-z_0)^n$$
$$a_n=\frac{f^n}{n!}$$

But where to from here? I want to eventually differentiate term by term to arrive at a Taylor series for $\frac{1}{z^2}$?

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+...$$

---

Applying this, we get:

> $$\frac1z=\frac12\left( 1-\frac{z-2}{2}+\frac{(z-2)^2}{4}-\frac{(z-2)^3}{8}+... \right)=\left( \frac12-\frac{z-2}{4}+\frac{(z-2)^2}{8}-\frac{(z-2)^3}{16}+... \right)$$